# Help with bibliographystyle in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I seem to be getting nowhere with my bibliography in LaTeX. Below is what I am using within my document. My reference page is blank for some reason.

Here is the main document structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

As shown in \cite[sec]

\bibliography{myref}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

I also have a file name `myref.bib`. Below is an example of a reference I am trying to use, which is declared in the `myref.bib` file.

```
 @ONLINE
  {sec,
    AUTHOR  = "Author.N",
    TITLE   = "{Title goes here}",
    URL = {http://www.here.com},
    URLYEAR = 2012,
    PRESORT="aa"
  }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: First, don't load both the `natbib` and `cite` packages; I suggest you only load the `natbib` package. Second, I don't think that the bibliography style file `ieeetr.bst` is one of the standard bibliography style files; did you maybe mean to specify `ieeetran(.bst)`? Third, one must encase the argument of a `\cite` command in curly braces, not square brackets. Fourth, be sure to also load the `url` package. Last but not least, be sure to run latex, bibtex, and latex twice more on your file. If these things don't work, check the `.log` and `.blg` files for errors and warning messages.

Comment: are you ensure to run bibtex with `yourfile.aux` and re-latex?
If you did this must have a `.blg` and `.bbl` files in the directory

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following MWE, it compiles on my system:

```
\listfiles    % shows list of used packages in log file 
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE{sec,
  AUTHOR  = {Author.N},
  TITLE   = {Title goes here},
  URL     = {http://www.here.com},
  URLYEAR = {2012},
  PRESORT = {aa},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}     % article IEEEtran
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{natbib}        % throws error
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

As shown in 
\cite{sec} 
%\cite[sec].                 % [] throws error/warning

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % ieeetran
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I have included the `bib` file in the MWE, changed the call with `\cite` (`{}` instead of `[]`) and corrected the bibliography style.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all, still get the same problem

Comment: I access the sharedLaTeX url to create my documents.